# How to assign a window procedure to a child window?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

Having such a simple Win32 app:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "gdiplus.lib")
using namespace Gdiplus;

const wchar_t g_szClassName[] = L"Skeleton";
const wchar_t g_szChildClassName[] = L"Child";

wchar_t msgbuf[100];

void Example_DrawImage9(HDC hdc) {
    Graphics graphics(hdc);
    Image image(L"C:/Users/Darek/Fallout2_older/data/art/iface/armor_info.bmp");
    graphics.DrawImage(&image, 0, 0);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_PAINT:   
        swprintf_s(msgbuf, _T("WM_PAINT - PARENT -  hwnd: %02X\n"), (int)hwnd);
        OutputDebugString(msgbuf);    
        return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcChild(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_PAINT:    
        swprintf_s(msgbuf, _T("WM_PAINT - CHILD -  hwnd: %02X\n"), (int)hwnd);
        OutputDebugString(msgbuf);
        return 0;    

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    ULONG_PTR token;
    GdiplusStartupInput input = { 0 };
    input.GdiplusVersion = 1;
    GdiplusStartup(&token, &input, NULL);

    //Step 1: Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, g_szClassName, L"Skeleton", WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER, 0, 0,  190, 110, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);    


    SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, 128, LWA_ALPHA);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // ---------------

        HWND hwnd_child;

        wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProcChild;   // 1
        wc.lpszClassName = g_szChildClassName;

        if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error!",
                MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
            return 0;
        }

        hwnd_child = CreateWindowEx(0, g_szClassName, L"Child", /*WS_POPUP |*/ WS_BORDER, 200, 0, 190, 110, hwnd, 0, hInstance, 0);

        swprintf_s(msgbuf, _T("hwnd_child: %02X\n"), (int)hwnd_child);
        OutputDebugString(msgbuf);    


        SetWindowLong(hwnd_child, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hwnd_child, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd_child, 0, 128, LWA_ALPHA);
        ShowWindow(hwnd_child, nCmdShow);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd_child);

    // ---------------

    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }

    GdiplusShutdown(token);
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

I've expected that the child window will run it's own `WndProcChild` window procedure but I get:

```
WM_PAINT - PARENT -  hwnd: C0996
hwnd_child: C0998
WM_PAINT - PARENT -  hwnd: C0998
```

what implies that the child window runs parent's procedure (`WndProc`) even if I've clearly assigned (line #1) a separate procedure for it.

Comment: `CreateWindowEx(0, g_szClassName` you call in both case.

Comment: @RbMm Yah, You're right. Changed to `g_szChildClassName` , and it works now. Big thx for pointing it out:-)

Comment: FYI, you can pass `WS_EX_LAYERED` to the `dwExStyle` parameter of `CreateWindowEx()`, you don't need to use `(Get|Set)WindowLong/Ptr(GWL_EXSTYLE)` after the window is created.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Ok, but what's the purpose of the `WS_EX_LAYERED` style. How does it change the child window behavior?

Comment: @Derek007 read the documentation: [Layered Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#layered-windows)